# Link to iOS app store on desktop opens App Store application instead staying on website

Tags: ios, macos, app-store, itunes, app-store-connect

On desktop some links to an iOS app store page open the "App Store preview" in the browser, like this one for example:

https://apps.apple.com/es/app/uber/id368677368

Which also generates a nice link preview.

But others instead of showing the the website, ask the user to open it on the App Store app:

[image]

If the user chooses not to the page stays blank.

Like this one for example:

https://apps.apple.com/app/id615238455

Is this is something configurable? If so, how?